# Error: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.from(Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilderSpec;)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, pmml

A strange run time error when working with JPMML library (with **guava**).

I used the jpmml related dependencies in my **pom.xml** like below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmml-evaluator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

It started throwing the exception. Then i tried like below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmml-evaluator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

I tried with 11.x/12.x/15.x/18.x/19.x/20.x versions of **guava** But still i am facing the same exception. I have gone through google and people have used **guava-19.0** version and it worked for them, But i am not able to achieve this. Can someone please tell me am i missing something.

Please find the full stack trace below.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.from(Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilderSpec;)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.CacheUtil.newCacheBuilder(CacheUtil.java:97)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.CacheUtil.buildLoadingCache(CacheUtil.java:90)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluator.<clinit>(ModelEvaluator.java:660)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorFactory.newModelEvaluator(ModelEvaluatorFactory.java:80)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorFactory.newModelEvaluator(ModelEvaluatorFactory.java:66)
.....
.....
```

Comment: You sure you're not pulling in a really old version (pre-12.0) of Guava somewhere else in your POM? Probably a transitive dependency of some kind?

Comment: I verified it i am not using any other versions of guava libraries.

Comment: Have you tried something like `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep guava`?

Comment: Got an output like this.  $ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep guava
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:provided - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
[INFO] |  |     \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:provided - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:provided - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:provided - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:provided - omitted for conflict with 19.0)

Comment: Looks OK. You are pulling in a version 11.0.2, but it seems like it's correctly omitted, so it should work. Figure out what package is pulling it in and try to add an `excusion` there...

Comment: @robby-cornelissen: I found one thing, we are using hadoop environment and running the jar in distributed mode, So, in hadoop environment where my jar is running, there i have guava 11.x version jar. So, now will it use guava library embedded with my jar or it will pick the one from environment.?

Comment: Seems like it's picking the one from the environment. The method you're receiving the error for was introduced in 12.0.

Comment: Well. Can you please suggest me how to pick the library embedded in my jar.

Comment: Sorry, clueless when it comes to Hadoop... Can't you upgrade the Hadoop version?

Comment: Thanks robby-cornelissen. It worked for me. I enabled `mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true` and then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have correct version in maven pom, but during runtime it is picking old version, make sure it picks the correct version at run time. Check your class path on the data nodes.

Comment: I am using cloudera hadoop, and class_path given to data nodes by cloudera itself. I think we should do some settings in pom to choose which version of jar (guava) need to be used by the code.

Comment: In this case I would create an Uber jar with all the dependencies.

Comment: It worked now. I used this code. conf.setBoolean(MRJobConfig.MAPREDUCE_JOB_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST, true);